# omniauth_saml with auth0 as the provider. Can not get user_metadata it returns "[object Object]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, saml, auth0

I am using multiple idps. One is OKTA and one is Auth0 but I found out I need a little bit more information about the user which is in the  user_metadata for auth0. When the data is returned its coming back as "[object Object]"  I also am using devise.

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :saml_okta,
name: :saml_okta,
strategy_class: ::OmniAuth::Strategies::SAML,
idp_cert_fingerprint: ENV['OKTA_CERT'],
idp_sso_target_url: ENV['OKTA_SSO']

config.omniauth :saml_auth0,
name: :saml_auth0,
strategy_class: ::OmniAuth::Strategies::SAML,
idp_cert_fingerprint: ENV['AUTH0_CERT'],
idp_sso_target_url: ENV['AUTH0_SSO'],
attribute_statements: {email: ['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'],
user_metadata: ['http://schemas.auth0.com/user_metadata/'] }
```

But the data that is returned looks like this:

```
provider: :saml_auth0
uid: foo@gmail.com
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  name: foo@gmail.com
  email: foo@gmail.com
  first_name:
  last_name:
  user_metadata: "[object Object]"
```

How can I get the user_metadata ?

Comment: Where are you getting `user_metadata` from? I don't see that as an option in Omniauth SAML https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml#options. Do you maybe want `request_attributes` instead?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  user_metadata is from auth0. Auth0 attributes were not mapping to SAML. But auth0 allows me to create rules to map the values I need for SAML. https://auth0.com/rules/saml-attribute-mapping